# How to add navigation menu with header line on the top

Tags: css, menu, navigation

image sample : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxZ8D.jpg

any one help to build css menu like this picture with hover and active.

especially line on the top of navigation menu with white dot when active and hover.

Comment: Its your home work. We can guide only

Comment: Try to search on Google. you can find plenty of same example. ofcourse you have to play a bit with colors.

Comment: i do, but the problem is **the line on the top of menu**

Comment: my problem [http://i.stack.imgur.com/SxZ8D.jpg](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SxZ8D.jpg)
Help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (I only tested on Chrome and Firefox, just to let you know):

```
nav ul li{
   display:inline-block;
   font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}

nav ul li a{
   padding:8px 10px 0 0;
   text-decoration:none;
   color:#F86659;
   border-top:6px #7F170E solid;
   font-size:.9em;
   margin:0;
}

nav ul li.selected a{
   color:#FFF;
}

.circle {
   background: #7F170E;
   width: 15px;
   height: 15px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   position:relative;
   left:-2px;
   top:-2px;
   margin:0 auto;
}

nav ul li.selected .circle{
   background: #FFF;
   border:4px #7F170E solid;
}
```

An example JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7P8qv/

Comment: this user wants more. :)

Comment: yeah, here is my problem [http://i.stack.imgur.com/SxZ8D.jpg](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SxZ8D.jpg)